# The import com.google cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: java

I have a problem in Eclipse. I took a class that O should created names SimpleGraph from a workspace in a class, but when I simply copy-paste the code it complains about the com.google not being able to resolve before compiling. My code:

```
    import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;

    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;

    /**
      * A directed graph with a fixed number of vertices and edges.
      *
      * <p>Each vertex is represented by an integer from 0 to n-1, where n is the number of
      * vertices in the graph.
      * <p>
      * Edges are stored with adjacency lists for each vertex.
      */
      public class SimpleGraph implements Graph<Integer> {
        private final int vertexCount;
        private final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adjacent;

      /**
        * Creates a graph with the edges listed in the second parameter.
        *
        * @param vertexCount number of vertices in the graph
        * @param edges array of directed edges in the format {@code {{source, dest}}}
        */
        public SimpleGraph(int vertexCount, int[]... edges) {
          Preconditions.checkArgument(vertexCount >= 0, "vertex count must be non-negative");
         this.vertexCount = vertexCount;
         adjacent = new HashMap<>(vertexCount);
         for (int i = 0; i < edges.length; ++i) {
          int u = edges[i][0];
          int v = edges[i][1];
          Preconditions.checkArgument(u != v, "cannot create loop at vertex %d", u);
          Preconditions.checkArgument(u >= 0 && u <= vertexCount && v >= 0 && v <= vertexCount,
      "cannot create edge from %d to %d in a graph with %d vertices", u, v, vertexCount);
          Set<Integer> adj = adjacent.get(u);
          if (adj == null) {
            adj = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // LinkedHashSet to use edge insertion order for iteration.
            adjacent.put(u, adj);
          }
          Preconditions.checkArgument(!adj.contains(v), "cannot create duplicate edge %d -> %d", u, v);
          adj.add(v);
         }
       }

       @Override public int vertexCount() {
         return vertexCount;
       }

       @Override public Collection<Integer> vertexSet() {
         return IntStream.range(0, vertexCount).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
       }

       @Override public Collection<Integer> neighbours(Integer v) {
         return Collections.unmodifiableSet(adjacent.getOrDefault(v, Collections.emptySet()));
       }

       /**
         * Returns a String representation of the vertices and edges of the graph.
         *
         * @return A String representation of the graph.
         */
         public String toString() {
          StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
          for (int u = 0; u < vertexCount; ++u) {
           str.append(String.format("Vertex %d", u));
           if (!neighbours(u).isEmpty()) {
            str.append(", outgoing edges:");
            for (int v : neighbours(u)) {
             str.append(String.format("\n\t%d -> %d", u, v));
            }
           }
           str.append("\n");
          }
          return str.toString();
         }
        }
```

Can somebody help how I am supposed to solve this problem? Should I import a JAR then where if I wasen tgiven any JAR files or a lib etc.

Comment: use this jar: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/28.2-jre/guava-28.2-jre.jar

Comment: Can you please mention your build method? Maven, Gradle or normal Eclipse Java Build?